# Error in plotting values by time: Error using bar: y values must be numeric or duration arrays

Tags: matlab

**Update**

This problem has now been added to the list of Millennium Prize Problems

**data:**

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1hAisMg233kfEqBSM4htdt77dRl37ce6s

**Script**

```
excelTable = readtable('excelfile.xlsx');
T = table2array(excelTable(1:end,3:end));

% S
a1 = T(18,3:end);
b1 = T(17,3:end);
c1 = T(16,3:end);
d1 = T(15,3:end);
e1 = T(14,3:end);

% H
a2 = T(12,3:end);
b2 = T(11,3:end);
c2 = T(10,3:end);
d2 = T(9,3:end);
e2 = T(8,3:end);

% HS
a3 = T(5,3:end);
b3 = T(4,3:end);
c3 = T(3,3:end);
d3 = T(2,3:end);
e3 = T(1,3:end);

% T
t = [1 2 3 4 5];

% Plotted
dates = [cat(3,e1,e2,e3); cat(3,d1,d2,d3); cat(3,c1,c2,c3); cat(3,b1,b2,b3); cat(3,a1,a2,a3)];
plotBarStackGroups(dates,t)

title('excel file')
xlabel('Time')
ylabel('Tail')
legend({'S', 'U/S', 'H','HS'})
legend('Location', 'southoutside')
legend('Orientation','horizontal')
```

**plotBarStackGroups**

```
function [] = plotBarStackGroups(stackData, groupLabels)

NumGroupsPerAxis = size(stackData, 1);
NumStacksPerGroup = size(stackData, 2);
% Count off the number of bins
groupBins = 1:NumGroupsPerAxis;
MaxGroupWidth = 0.65; % Fraction of 1. If 1, then we have all bars in groups touching
groupOffset = MaxGroupWidth/NumStacksPerGroup;
figure
hold on; 
for i=1:NumStacksPerGroup
Y = squeeze(stackData(:,i,:));

% Center the bars:

internalPosCount = i - ((NumStacksPerGroup+1) / 2);

% Offset the group draw positions:
groupDrawPos = (internalPosCount)* groupOffset + groupBins;

h(i,:) = barh(Y, 'stacked');
set(h(i,:),'BarWidth',groupOffset);
set(h(i,:),'XData',groupDrawPos);
end
hold off;
set(gca,'YTickMode','manual');
set(gca,'YTick',1:NumGroupsPerAxis);
set(gca,'YTickLabelMode','manual');
set(gca,'YTickLabel',groupLabels);
end
```

**ERROR**

> Error using bar (line 175) y values must be numeric or duration
>   arrays.
>
> Error in LS (line 31) plotBarStackGroups(dates,t)

**ISSUE**

I want the result to BE plotted with respect to time. The values in the arrays should BE changing with time. I cannot convert them to numeric value because they have to BE time.

**Response to Sol 1**

Changed Code:

```
function [] = plotBarStackGroups(stackData, groupLabels)

NumGroupsPerAxis = size(stackData, 1);
NumStacksPerGroup = size(stackData, 2);
% Count off the number of bins
groupBins = 1:NumGroupsPerAxis;
MaxGroupWidth = 0.65; % Fraction of 1. If 1, then we have all bars in groups touching
groupOffset = MaxGroupWidth/NumStacksPerGroup;
figure
hold on; 
for i=1:NumStacksPerGroup
unixtime=(arrayfun(@(x) posixtime(x), stackData));
Y = squeeze(unixtime(:,i,:));

% Center the bars:

internalPosCount = i - ((NumStacksPerGroup+1) / 2);

% Offset the group draw positions:
groupDrawPos = (internalPosCount)* groupOffset + groupBins;

h(i,:) = barh(Y, 'stacked');
set(h(i,:),'BarWidth',groupOffset);
set(h(i,:),'XData',groupDrawPos);
end
hold 

off;
set(gca,'YTickMode','manual');
set(gca,'YTick',1:NumGroupsPerAxis);
set(gca,'YTickLabelMode','manual');
set(gca,'YTickLabel',groupLabels);
end
```

Result

[image: Result]

How I want it

[image: Want]

Comment: please upload the data as a file, I cannot reproduce the problem with the pasted text. see here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @yuvalHarpaz the data file has been uploaded

Answer (score 0):

the error message is clear - your Y array is not numeric, so it can't plot. If you set a break point in that line, you can see Y is an array of datetime object.

To convert it to a numeric array, there are a few ways, one way is call function posixtime(). like this

```
unixtime=(arrayfun(@(x) posixtime(x), stackData));
Y = squeeze(unixtime(:,i,:));
h(i,:) = barh(Y, 'stacked');
```

now you can plot the stack-bar plot.

Comment: Please have a look at the revised question that contains the results of your comment. It was able to plot the array but not in the manner I would like @FangQ